# Prevent Vim from Double Mapping

Tags: windows, vim, mapping

I want to append `['']` to the end of the line while in Insert Mode, so I have this mapping:

```
inoremap <C-[> <Esc>A['']<Esc>hi
```

The problem is that Vim also maps `A['']<Esc>hi` to `<Esc>` in Insert Mode. To get out of Insert Mode, I have to press `<Ctrl-C>`.

How do I stop the double mapping?

I'm using gVim on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the mapping doesn't work not like what you said that map `A['']<Esc>hi` to `<esc>`.

the keycode of `<esc>` is same as `ctrl-[` both are 27.

you could choose other key-combinations, like `<F2> -<F12>, or <c-l> ...` your mapping is gonna work.

detail, pls check:

```
:h keycode
```

then `/esc`

Comment: well...maybe.. :) but there are a lot of people pressing `<c-[>` as `<esc>`, because the fingers move shorter distance, for those people it is not coincidence. :)  some others map `jj` as `<esc>` and some swap `capslock and esc`...

Comment: Yeah, kinda figured the coincidence was less for others than it was for me.  I've never understood why people consider the <ESC> key to be so much work... It comes quite naturally for me to hit <ESC>.  I always disable my capslock key completely!